# Getting rid of qt.qpa.plugin Error?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I am trying to execute standalone python script outside QGIS. But when I try to initialize Qgs Application , it give me below error . I don't have any idea how to get rid of it .

```
from qgis.core import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis")
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
```

---

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
>   This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could
>   be    initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Comment: In Python \ in Strings marks special characters, eg. \n for newline. Your prefix path should not have backslashes, use / instead...

Comment: @AndreasMüller I did that correction , but still I am getting same error

Comment: It could be your environment. To start qgis, you'll need an environment like in qgis.bat. You can use a copy of that to call python or an IDE you want to use. Just replace the qgis call in the last line.